# How to evaluate values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary (`d`).
I want to use this dictionary with different values for `a` and `b`.

How can I update the dictionary's output without calling the whole dictionary again?

```
a=1
b=2
d = {'value_1': a+b , 'value_2':a-b}
```

Comment: You can't. `d` isn't storing references to the operations; it's storing the results of those operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your feedback to my [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60192541/355230), it sounds like what you want is something that behaves more-or-less like a spreadsheet. Below is how to implement one that is very dictionary-like. It's based on Raymond Hettinger's ActiveState [recipe](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/355045-spreadsheet) by that name with some modifications and extensions.

Note that except for the special case of keyword arguments passed when an instance of the class is created, the values in it should all be **strings**, not numerical values.

Also note that since it uses `eval()`, for security purposes it should only be used with input from trusted sources.

I think it's important to understand that although the `Spreadsheet` class presented below isn't technically a dictionary, it behaves a lot like (a subclass of) one and if used instead of a regular dictionary will give you the capabilities you want. See the description of [**mapping**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-mapping) in the online documentation's glossary.

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping

class SpreadSheet(MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, tools=None, **kwargs):
        self._cells = {}
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            self._cells[key] = value if isinstance(value, str) else str(value)
        self._tools = {'__builtins__': None}  # Prevent eval() from supplying.
        if tools is not None:
            self._tools.update(tools)  # Add any caller-supplied functions.

    def clear(self):
        return self._cells.clear()

    def copy(self):
        return self._cells.copy()

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key in self._cells

    def __setitem__(self, key, formula):
        self._cells[key] = formula

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return eval(self._cells[key], self._tools, self)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._cells)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._cells)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self._cells[key]

    def getformula(self, key):
        """ Return raw un-evaluated contents of cell. """
        return self._cells[key]

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for k, v in dict(*args, **kwargs).items():
            self[k] = v
```

Sample usage:

```
d = SpreadSheet(a=1, b=2)
d.update({'x': 'x1',
          'x1': 'a+2',
          'x2': 'b+1',
          'x3': 'a+b'})
xx = d['x']
print(xx)  # -> 3
```

Comment: Thanks again for the nice solution. I want to avoid extra lines in the code. So first, I changed the variables in dic to the string and I did the following:    a = 1
    b = 2
    x = 'x1'
    y = {'x1' : 'a+2', 'x2' : 'b+1', 'x3' : 'a+b'}
    xx = eval ( y [ x ] )
    print(xx) # the answer is 3 , The problem is that if the first string"x= {'x1,'x2'} The eval function doesn't work.

Comment: From your comment it sounds like you don't understanding how to use the class in my answer. You don't need to explicitly use `eval()` with it as that happens automatically, plus you should be using an instance of it not a regular dictionary.

Comment: Karen: Hopefully the sample usage I added to my answer should clarify things.

Comment: It helped indeed, Thanks. I am trying to program efficiently,  more clear  and understandable. Anyone should be able to understand the code without googling.

Comment: Good to hear. As for not having to google—well, it's worthy goal… `;¬)`

Comment: Anther thing I think it's important to point out is the values don't have to string representation of numeric values, names of other cells, or mathematical formulas. They can be other types and the "formulas" are just Python expressions which can include calls to functions provided in the optional `tools` dictionary argument or object method calls. An example of the latter: if `d['s'] = '"foobar"'`, you could define `d['cap'] = 's.upper()'` to have its evaluated value when referenced be `"FOOBAR"`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by storing *functions* in a separate dictionary and then create new ones by evaluating it.

Here's a simple example illustrating what I'm suggesting:

```
funcs = {'value_1': lambda: a+b,
         'value_2': lambda: a-b}

a=1
b=2
d = {k: v() for k, v in funcs.items()}
print(d)  # -> {'value_1': 3, 'value_2': -1}

a=3
b=5
d = {k: v() for k, v in funcs.items()}
print(d)  # -> {'value_1': 8, 'value_2': -2}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works but I am looking for a solution without changing the dictionary.

Comment: When do you expect/want these dictionary values to be evaluated? What triggers it? I ask because I have another idea…

Comment: I defined a dictionary to use it later and compare it with some results in a simulation. When I define the dictionary I have to give inputs to it (a,b) then it remains in the memory. But I want to be flexible and change a,b whenever I call the dictionary.